# passing string to event listener giving NULL

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code. The string is being sent to `uploadFile` correctly but the line `alert(str)` is giving me `undefined`?

```
function uploadFile(str){
    alert(str); //prints correctly
    var fileTag = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    var file = fileTag.files[0];
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("thefile", file); 
    xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", function(evt,str){
         alert(str); //undefined
    }, false);
    ....
}
```

I'm fairly new to javascript, so can anyone tell me why this is happening? thank you

Comment: What makes you think that the load event handler will receive two arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event handler function receives a single parameter: an `event` object.

Your event handler

```
function(evt,str) { }
```

expects two parameters. Naturally, as it doesn't receive the second one, `str`, you get that `str` is undefined.

If you want your event handler to use the `str` variable which is defined as a parameter of `function uploadFile(str){ }`, however, you can do that, because the evet handler function is defined inside the `uploadFile(str){ }` function. This is called a closure. Just change

```
function(evt, str){ }
```

to

```
function(evt) { }
```

This way, you remove the inner definition of `str`, which hided the outer one, in `uploadFile(str)`. So in

```
xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", function(evt,str){
     alert(str);
}, false);
```

you will really get the alert of the string `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `str` from function declaration

```
xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", function(evt){
     alert(str); //alerts str
}, false);
```